# php only shows two entries from db

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spieler` (
`spielerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
`vorname` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
`jahrgang` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
`bemerkung` varchar(300) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
`mannschaft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci;

ALTER TABLE `spieler`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`spielerID`),
ADD KEY `mannschaft` (`mannschaft`);
ALTER TABLE `spieler`
MODIFY `spielerID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `spieler`
ADD CONSTRAINT `spieler_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mannschaft`) REFERENCES `mannschaft` (`mannschaftID`);
```

and the php code to get the data out of the db:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
//echo "ID ist".$id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM spieler WHERE mannschaft = '.$id.'";
if (!$result = $db->query($sql)) {
 die("Fehler: ['.$db->error.']");
}
echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo "<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Vorname</b></td><td><b>Jahrgang</b></td><td><b>Bemerkung</b></td><td><b>Bearbeiten</b></td><td><b>Löschen</b></td></tr>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$row['spielerID'] . '</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['vorname'].'</td><td>'.$row['jahrgang'].'</td><td>'.$row['bemerkung'].'</td><td><a href="bearbeiten.php?spielerID='.$row['spielerID'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td><td><a href="delete.php?spielerID='.$row['spielerID'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

The above code works perfectly fine if there are only two entries in the table. But if there are more then two entries, the table is not getting displayed. It only shows the tablehead.

What am I doing wrong? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sql query like give below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM spieler WHERE mannschaft = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! Can you explain this behavior? Why is it working with two entires and not with three?

Comment: I think the value of $id in your query only match to 2 row of your table values that's why it will give you two rows. If you want to check, print your query and check the value of $id and then check your table.

Comment: so my query looks like this `SELECT * FROM spieler WHERE mannschaft = '.1.'` and the new query looks like `SELECT * FROM spieler WHERE mannschaft = '1'` but both times the ids in the table all were 1

Comment: I think it check ascii value of '.' in your table.